# Prove that there is no polynomial with integer coefficients such that $p(a)=b,\,p(b)=c,\,p(c)=a$ for distinct integers $a,b,c$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, polynomials

Our teacher gave us this question but I am very stuck. I drew graphs to see why it cant be true but I didnt find anything. I see that if $p$ existed then: $$p(\cdots p(a))=a,\;p(\cdots p(b))=b,\;p(\cdots p(c))=c$$

(With $3n$ $p$'s). But I don't know where the contradiction is... Maybe we can work on the divisibility of the polynomials coefficients or something?

Comment: The integer coefficients condition is important. Recall that $x - y | p(x) - p(y)$.

Comment: If we could integers mod 3, then x+1 would work actually as p(0)=1,p(1)=2,p(2)=0.  Thus one has to be careful about what domain is one using here.

Comment: Its nothing but proving $a=b=c$. Right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint** $\ $ Writing $\rm\,px\,$ for $\rm\,p(x)\,$ and applying the Factor Theorem we have

$$\rm\,\ a\!-\!b\mid pa\!-\!pb = b\!-\!c\mid pb\!-\!pc=c\!-\!a\mid pc\!-\!pa = a\!-\!b\ $$

therefore we deduce $\rm\,\ a\!-\!b\mid b\!-\!c\mid c\!-\!a\mid a\!-\!b\ $ hence $\rm\ \ldots$

Comment: This would be much clearer if you wrote p(a) for pa, etc.

Comment: @Chris But all the parens would make the structure less clear.

Comment: I can see your point, but it did confuse me for a bit.

Comment: @Chris That's why I prepended a notational remark. Thanks for the feedback.